# A detail about busy beaverly behavior of distortion functions in graph groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, computability-theory

Say a function $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is *weakly superrecursive* if for any total recursive $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
we have $\phi(n) > \psi(n)$ for infinitely many $n$. Say it is *strongly superrecursive* if for any total recursive $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$
we have $\phi(n) > \psi(n)$ for all large enough $n$. Not every weakly superrecursive function is strongly superrecursive.

Let $H \leq G$ be groups with finite generating sets $S \subset T$, respectively. Define the *distortion function* of $H$ inside $G$ as
$$ \Delta^T_S(\ell) = \max \{|w|_S \;|\; w \in H, |w|_T \leq \ell\}, $$
defined up to the equivalence relation $f \approx g$ if for some $C > 0$, $C^{-1}f(n) \leq g(n) \leq Cf(n)$ for large enough $n$, where $|w|_N$ is the word norm of $w$ under generators $N$.

By a result of Mihajlova, $G = F_2 \times F_2$ has undecidable generalized word problem, and from this it follows that there is a finitely-generated
subgroup $H \leq G$ with weakly superrecursive distortion function.

> Does this group, or at least some other graph group (i.e. right-angled Artin group), have strongly superrecursive distortion function?

Might follow from computability principles directly (if so, feel free to ignore groups in the answer), but I don't see this. Might also follow from Mihajlova's construction, but while I know the construction I haven't reconstructed a proof, and I don't know the details of how the word problem of f.p. groups is proved undecidable well enough either. Might also be well-known about graph groups, but I didn't find such a statement.

*Mikhajlova, K. A.*, [**The occurrence problem for free products of groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/SM1968v004n02ABEH002788), Math. USSR, Sb. 4(1968), 181-190 (1969); Translation from Mat. Sb., n. Ser. 75(117), 199-210 (1968). [ZBL0214.27403](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0214.27403).

Comment: A theorem of Olshanskii-Sapir is that the class of Dehn functions of finitely presented groups coincides with the class of distortion functions for finitely generated subgroups of $F \times F$. So as long as you find a f.p. group with strongly superrecursive Dehn function, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

> Theorem. There exists a finitely-presented group with strongly superrecursive Dehn function.

> Theorem. (Therefore) there exists a finitely-generated subgroup of $F_2 \times F_2$ with strongly superrecursive distortion.

These follow from theorems 1.2. The connection pointed out in the comment of @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda.

> Theorem 1.2 (Olshanskii-Sapir '98). The set of distortion functions of finitely generated subgroups of the direct product of two free groups $F_2 \times F_2$ coincides (up to equivalence) with the set of all Dehn functions of finitely presented groups.

> Theorem 1.2 (Sapir-Birget-Rips, '08). Let $D_4$ be the set of all Dehn functions $d(n) \geq n^4$ of finitely presented groups. Let $T_4$ be the set of time functions $t(n) \geq n^4$ of arbitrary Turing machines. Let $T^4$ be the set of superadditive functions which are fourth powers of time functions. Then $T^4 \subset D_4 \subset T_4$.

The *time function* of a (not necessarily deterministic) Turing machine $M$ is $t : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ where $t(n)$ is the smallest number such that for every acceptable word $w$
with $|w| \leq n$ there exists a computation of length $\leq t(n)$ which accepts $w$. A function $f$ is *superadditive* if $f(m+n) \geq f(m) + f(n)$.
All we need to do is find a function in $T^4$ which is strongly superrecursive.

Let $M$ be a Turing machine that on input $0^n 1^k 2^h$ performs the following $2^{n+k+h}$ times, in a loop: simulate the $n$th Turing machine $M'$ (i.e. the machine with Gödel number $n$) on all unary inputs $1^0, 1^1, ..., 1^{2k}$, until $M'$ has halted on all of them. (And $M$ does not halt on inputs not of this form.) Let $t$ be the Time function of $M$. Letting $a = \max(a,b)$, we have $t(a + b)^4 \geq t(a + 1)^4 \geq (2t(a))^4 \geq t(a)^4 + t(b)^4$, where $t(a + 1) \geq 2t(a)$ follows because if $t(a)$ is given by input $0^n 1^k 2^h$, then the computation on $0^n 1^k 2^{h+1}$ takes at least twice as long. Therefore, $t(n)^4$ is superadditive.

(The justification of $t(a + 1) \geq 2t(a)$ is not completely precise, since there's a lot of bookkeeping going on and kept implicit. To be more exact without going into Turing machine details, you could replace the $2^{n+k+h}$-length loop on $0^n 1^k 2^h$ by two recursive calls of $M$ on $0^n 1^k 2^{h-1}$, when $h > 0$, or alternatively replace $2^{n+k+h}$ by something that grows much faster.)

For a Turing machine $M'$, write $\alpha(M')$ for some Gödel number of it.
Let $f$ be any total recursive function, computed by some Turing machine $M'$, let $\alpha(M') = \ell$. Total recursive functions are the same if we restrict to unary, so we may suppose that on input $1^k$, $M'$ computes $1^{f(k)}$ and halts (and does whatever on other inputs). We may assume $M'$ takes at least $f(k)$ steps to halt on input $1^k$ (indeed this is automatic since it has to write its output).

Now, on input $0^{\ell} 1^k$ our machine $M$ halts (because $M'$ halts on all unary inputs), and takes (much more than) $\max_{i=0}^{2k} f(i)$ steps to do so.
In particular, as soon as $n \leq 2(n-\ell)$, we have $t(n)^4 \geq t(n) \geq f(n)$.
Therefore $t(n)^4$ is strongly superrecursive.

Since $n^4$ is recursive, we also have $t(n)^4 \geq n^4$ (up to equivalence).

*Ol’shanskij, Alexander Yu.; Sapir, Mark V.*, [**Length and area functions on groups and quasi-isometric Higman embeddings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218196701000401), Int. J. Algebra Comput. 11, No. 2, 137-170 (2001). [ZBL1025.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1025.20030).

*Sapir, Mark V.; Birget, Jean-Camille; Rips, Eliyahu*, [**Isoperimetric and isodiametric functions of groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3597195), Ann. Math. (2) 156, No. 2, 345-466 (2002). [ZBL1026.20021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1026.20021).

Comment: Nice one! I suspected the answer would be yes. I wouldn't be surprised if something like this can be found in the literature already (though I don't know where to find it), as statements like "the word problem is really really hard!" are always appealing to publish. Nevertheless, it is very nice to have it written up here.

Comment: On the other hand, it bears pointing out that the Dehn function is only, of course, an upper bound on the complexity of the word problem!

Comment: I see, so indeed maybe I should've gone one step further and proved directly that the word problem takes strongly superrecursive time to solve in a suitable sense. I imagine that's true since the proofs (of course) involve embedding universal computation, but one would probably need to actually read the construction. If someone connects the dots here I'll accept that as an answer, so we get the best result on top (also I'm hesitant of giving myself the points, especially as it was not very difficult from the literature pointer).

Comment: It's a shame this question wasn't asked a few months ago before Sapir left MO!